# Login with hashed password c#

Tags: c#, sql, hash

Will I be able to login with password which is hashed in a database if I have code like this:

```
string queryLog = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = @username and password = @password";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryLog, con))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", LoginUsername_txt.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", LoginPassword_txt.Text);

                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                    DataSet dts = new DataSet();
                    adpt.Fill(dts);
                    con.Close();

                    if (dts.Tables[0].Rows.Count >= 1)
                    {
                        passingText = LoginUsername_txt.Text;
                        this.Hide();
                        Work_Orders d = new Work_Orders();
                        d.ShowDialog();
                    }
                    else MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password!", "Error signing in!");
                }
```

As you can see I'm checking if I get at least 1 result back from database. But what happens if password is hashed in the database.

Comment: You take the user's password, hash it the same way as was done in the database, then query with the hashed password instead of the plain text password.

Comment: Is it also salted? How **exactly** did you hash it?

Answer (score 1):

The password is [rightly so] stored as a hash for security reasons; but once hashed, it is stored as a `string`, and comparable directly to that exact string. Your code would currently require you *to use the hashed password string as the password* - not an ideal scenario...

What needs to happen is an intermediary step:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Hash(LoginPassword_txt.Text));
```

Where `string Hash(string password)` is a function that will hash the password using the same hashing algorithm that was used at the time the account was created (and password stored in the database).

Comment: Note this may not be sufficient if salting is used. If salting is used, you likely need to query the record out (by the username alone) and then do the hashing and salting and then compare the password values outside of the database.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to Login with the Hashed password, you need to Hash the password you received from the `Password TextBox` using the same algorithm you used to hash the password stored in the database before and then pass the it to the sql query.

```
string hasedPassword = Hash(PasswordTextBox.Text);  // TODO: Make a Hash() function
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@geslo", hasedPassword );
```

Comment: `hashPasswordTextBox.Text` - do you expect the user to enter a ... hash of their password into this magical textbox?

Comment: Right - so what's your code example doing??? I suggested an edit that makes a bit more sense, please review it.